# Android: Is it possible to check if a device supports global network mode?

Tags: android, wireless, telephony, android-package-managers

Is it possible to check if the users device supports GSM/Global Network?

I have tried:

```
pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY_GSM)
```

However it does not seem to work as it returns `false` for my device which is on a CDMA network (but also has a GSM radio in it).

It seems as though there is no surefire way to check if a users device supports "Global" capabilities.

Logs of features in the phone (I am on Verizon).

```
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42977d20 com.verizon.hardware.telephony.ehrpd fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42977db8 android.hardware.location fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42977e38 android.hardware.screen.landscape fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42977ec8 android.hardware.screen.portrait fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42977f58 android.hardware.camera.any fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42977fe0 android.hardware.bluetooth fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42978060 android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42978110 com.sec.feature.gearmanager fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42978198 com.sec.feature.hovering_ui fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42978220 android.hardware.microphone fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{429782a8 com.verizon.hardware.telephony.lte fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42978338 android.hardware.camera.autofocus fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{429783c8 android.software.live_wallpaper fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42978458 com.vzw.hardware.ehrpd fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{429784d0 com.vmware.mvp fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42978538 android.hardware.faketouch fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{429785b8 android.hardware.camera fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42978638 com.sec.feature.minimode fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{429786b8 android.software.sip.voip fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42978738 android.hardware.sensor.proximity fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{429787c8 com.sec.feature.irda_service fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42978850 android.hardware.telephony.cdma fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{429788e0 android.hardware.wifi fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42978958 android.hardware.location.network fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{429789e8 android.hardware.nfc fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42978a60 com.sec.android.mdm fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42978ad8 android.hardware.bluetooth_le fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42978b60 android.software.input_methods fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42978be8 android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42978c78 com.sec.feature.sensorhub fl=0x2}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42978cf8 com.sec.feature.yosemite fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42978d78 android.hardware.wifi.direct fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42978e00 android.hardware.usb.accessory fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42978e88 android.hardware.sensor.light fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42978f10 android.software.app_widgets fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42978f98 android.hardware.camera.flash fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42979020 com.sec.feature.barcode_emulator fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{429790b0 android.hardware.telephony fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42979130 com.sec.feature.flashbar fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{429791b0 android.software.sip fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42979228 android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.jazzhand fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{429792d8 android.hardware.sensor.barometer fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42979368 android.hardware.usb.host fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{429793e8 android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42979488 android.hardware.sensor.compass fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42979518 com.vzw.hardware.lte fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42979590 android.software.home_screen fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42979618 com.sec.feature.multiwindow.phone fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{429796a8 com.amazon.fv.feature.preload fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42979730 android.hardware.location.gps fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{429797b8 com.sec.feature.multiwindow fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42979840 android.hardware.camera.front fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{429798c8 android.hardware.touchscreen fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.295  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{42979950 android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer fl=0x1}
04-10 11:44:24.305  14651-14651/com.globalreadycheck.app E/FEATURE INFO:﹕ FeatureInfo{429799e8 glEsVers=3.0 fl=0x0}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
    FeatureInfo[] fInfo = packageManager.getSystemAvailableFeatures();

     while(i < fInfo.length)
     {
        if(fInfo[i].toString().equal(FEATURE_TELEPHONY_GSM))
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GSM supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(fInfo[i].toString().equal(FEATURE_TELEPHONY_CDMA))
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CDMA supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: This returns -1 in my case.  Same issue as I had with the other check.

Comment: I had tried this as well and GSM did not turn up in the features.  Only android.hardware.telephony.cdma.  Maybe the carrier disabled this somehow?

Comment: @IZI_Shadow_IZI You can only be connected to a single network at a time. So that's why you are getting this problem

Comment: That is what I was thinking might be the issue.  My issue is that I need to let the user know that their device does support global even if they haven't enabled it yet (I then show them a prompt for how to switch to the global network).

Comment: Note that GSM & CDMA are two different networking technologies. Only one of them can be active at a time in a device. So that's the reason for the problem you are facing.

Comment: @IZI_Shadow_IZI yayyy ! :D